# Display file name in println

Tags: java, file

I am trying to  figure out how to display my file name in the println the the following code using the file object properties. I am new to this and could use some guidance in the right direction. The idea is to have "Excercise19_2.txt" displayed on the console. I hope that makes it clearer to everyone. Thanks for your help!

```
package chp19_1_b;
import java.io.*;

public class Excercise19_1_b {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Excercise19_2.txt"));

        output.writeObject(numbers);
        output.writeObject(new java.util.Date());
        output.writeDouble(5.5);

        output.close();

        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Excercise19_2.txt"));

        //Print FileName
        ;

        int[] newNumbers = (int[])(input.readObject());

        //Print array
        System.out.println("Integers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < newNumbers.length; i++)
            System.out.println(newNumbers[i] + ", ");

        //Print date
        java.util.Date date = (java.util.Date)(input.readObject());
        System.out.println("DateTime: " + date);


        //Print double
        double number = input.readDouble();
        System.out.println("Double: " + number);


        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just adding the filename to the println? Or including another println? Your question doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Kane I agree, although it's not clear if the OP wants the full path or not. The string is already there; if it was refactored into a local, could just print it.

Answer (score 3):

You'd likely want to create an actual [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html), and use something like [`file.getCanonicalPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29) or [`.getAbsolutePath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) depending on your needs. Creating a `FileInputStream` directly from the path bypasses the ability to query the actual file.

You can still create the `FileInputStream` using the [`File`-based constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.io.File%29).

To @Kane's point, you have the filename right there--if you just want to duplicate what you're currently using (i.e., you don't care about the *actual* path, just the filename), refactor it into a local variable:

```
String filename = "Exercise19_2.txt";
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
out.println(filename);
```

Or have it as a class constant.

Comment: At this point I am just trying to get the program to display the file name "Exercise19_2.txt" on a separate line. I don't have the code in there but it should go where you see //Print Filename.

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong on that. I want to display the file properties.